# How to get only a few columns from several data frames obtained from using the lapply function?

Tags: r

I have this function "get_animals" that retrieves data for several specimens of different species of animals. It works by giving a vector with several species names, and it retrieves the data regarding those species (location, dna sequences ...). The thing is that the data base I'm using can't handle a query with too many species names in a single line of code, so I'm trying to use lapply to get one by one.

I tried this:

```
species_list<-as.list(as.character(unique(df$species_name)))
e<-lapply(species_list, function (x) get_animals(animal_names=x))
```

The thing is that the lapply returns a series of data frames with too many columns for each species name in "species_list", and what I wanted was only two columns from each data frame, and then I aimed to fuse all those data frame in a single one.

I tried to unlist the result from the lapply function:

```
e<-unlist(e)
```

But it didn't work because it just returned all the occurences for the first column of each data frame.

Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to subset the columns, use either  the column index

```
lapply(species_list, function (x) get_animals(animal_names=x)[c(1, 5)])
```

Or column name

```
lapply(species_list, function (x) 
          get_animals(animal_names=x)[c("species_name", "location")])
```

Comment: just some follow ups, if I want to get the columns by name can I just get_animals(animal_names=x)[df$species_name,df$location] ?
and another one, how do I unlist the list of data frame so that I can have them individually? thanks for the answer

Comment: @tadeufontes  Yes, just the column name in `c(...)` updated the answer